# Insufficient permissions for SpeechRecognizer despite setting it in the manifest

Tags: android

I'm just trying to create a dummy app for speech recognition on clicking a button (with no pop-ups or anything).

My Android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="billobob.org.speechtest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the fragment housing what's actually going on:

```
package myandroid.org.speechtest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Simple app for recognizing speech
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1234;

    private TextView mSpeechTextView1;
    private TextView mSpeechTextView2;
    private Button mSpeechButton;
    private String speechString;
    private SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
    private Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
    boolean mIsListening = false;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mSpeechTextView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mSpeechTextView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mSpeechButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.speechButton);
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this.getContext());
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getActivity().getPackageName());


        SpeechRecognitionListener listener = new SpeechRecognitionListener();
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);

        mSpeechButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mIsListening)
                {
                    Log.d("UUXX", "clicked");
                    mIsListening = true;
                    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (mSpeechRecognizer != null)
        {
            mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
            mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
            mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    protected class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            Log.d("UUSP", "in read");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("UUSP", "begin!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("UUSP", "end");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            Log.d("UUSP", matches != null ? matches.get(0) : null);
            mIsListening = false;
            mSpeechTextView1.setText(matches.get(0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            Log.d("UUSP", "partial...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
            Log.d("UUSP", "event?");
        }
    }
}
```

The button registers the click, but nothing else happens. I noticed in the non-application log that the error:

```
05-20 20:56:32.022 18200-19108/? E/RecognitionService: call for recognition service without RECORD_AUDIO permissions
```

Always occurs, despite the fact that I ostensibly have permissions set in the manifest. I'm testing it on a 6P with Android Studio 2.1. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For API 23+ (Android 6.0) it is not enough to just add permissions to the manifest. You need to request permissions at run time.

See the developer documents for more information:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

You can verify this is the issue by changing your gradle `targetSdkVersion` back to 21. It will then use the old permission model on devices running API 23+

Comment: Small code snippet would significantly improve the answer (at least for newbies in Android like me).

Comment: @OleksandrShpota it looks like the code snippet wouldn't be that small, but this might help https://ptyagicodecamp.github.io/requesting-audio-permission-at-runtime.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this code snippet at the instant where you want to access the audio recording feature.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
```

This is asking for a run time permission to access the feature of recording audio. You can add any number of permissions in that array.

Add this in you manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```